# Pdf object stream encoded

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I'm having a pdf encoded in a strange codification that I cannot read.

This is an example of an object stream when a I'm reading the buffer:

`BT
1 0 0 -1 9670 5386 Tm
(.&RY!) Tj
610 0 Td
(.&R%!) Tj
570 0 Td
(.%R$!) Tj
-10310 -244 Td
(KSAK4UOH^.]SKHFS.@SKHF^S.H]) Tj
5954 0 Td
(!V) Tj
-961 0 Td
(!&#!%#%!!") Tj
1356 0 Td
(&!!) Tj
-2722 0 Td
(&.!!!!!'%W!$&&"b) Tj
ET`

I tried to uncompress with pdftk and qpdf but it did not work.

It looks like is encrypted, but when I do  `qpdf --show-encryption file.pdf`, it says: "file is not encrypted".

When I use `pdftotext file.pdf output.txt`, I can read the output file perfectly, so that makes me think it has to be a special codification...

Any suggestions?

Comment: That looks like the content stream of a page, some xobject, or some annotation. What you have is no PDF but merely a part of it.

Comment: Yeah I know, but the whole buffer looks like that, and it is a pdf file of the version 1.3.

Comment: Does it start with `%PDF-1.3`? If it doesn't, it's not the complete PDF.

Comment: It does: %PDF-1.3
%\E2\E3\CF\D3
58 0 obj

Comment: Ok... 2 remarks... Between `1.3` and `%` there should be a line break. Is there? If there isn't, the file is broken beyond repair.  And furthermore, the \E2 etc should actually each be some special, non-ASCII character.  It looks like those special characters are encoded using '\' and the hex-encoded character code. This might be reversible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PDF is encoded with CMAPs - http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2012/05/understanding-the-pdf-file-format-embedded-cmap-tables/